# Can we delete a specific bucket in hive table?

Tags: hive, bigdata

if my table data is inserted into 10 buckets, is it possible to delete any bucket from hive CLI eg: delete bucket 4 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No It is DDL .

Metadata should be updated in that case You have to drop table and reinsert data into the table .